# dynamically created imageview in gridlayout not working

Tags: android, gridview, grid-layout, image-capture

I want to set captured image to dynamically created imageview in same gridlayout but it creates a new grid layout and sets the captured image to the new gridview.

This is my `mainactivity.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Damage_Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Damage_Item>();
    CustomAdapter_back customGridAdapter;
    GridLayout mContainerView;
    int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    ImageView dynamic_imageview;
    LinearLayout dynamic_linearview;
    String image1;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContainerView = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.describedamage_gridview) ;
        //gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

        Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                inflateImageRow();
            }
        });

    }

    public void selectImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 140, 150, true);
        Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream1);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest); //bmp is the bitmap to dwaw into
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(resized, 0f, 0f, null);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(1, 145, 100, 130, paint);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        paint.setTextSize(10);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        float height = paint.measureText("yY");
        canvas.drawText(dateTime, 5f, height+130f, paint);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String image1 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //arrayList_image.add(image1);
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(dest);
        //holder.imageItem.setBackground(background);
        Damage_Item damage_item = new Damage_Item();
        damage_item.setTemp_image(dest);
        gridArray.add(damage_item);

        customGridAdapter = new CustomAdapter_back(MainActivity.this, gridArray);
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);


        /*gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this)*/;



    }
    int count;
    private void inflateImageRow() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_row, null);
        dynamic_imageview = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_imageview);

        dynamic_linearview=(LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_linear);

            dynamic_imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //image_flagdynamic_right = true;
                 selectImage();
            }
        });
        count= mContainerView.getChildCount()-1;
        dynamic_imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
            int parent=((View) v.getParent()).getId();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Whould you like to delete this image?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        int index = ((View) v.getParent()).getId() + 2;

                        try {
                            mContainerView.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                            // arrayList_image.remove(((View) v.getParent()).getId());
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        mContainerView.addView(rowView, mContainerView.getChildCount() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }
}
```

this is my adapter file `CustomAdapter_back.java`

```
public class CustomAdapter_back extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Damage_Item> Damage_Item;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView button;

    public CustomAdapter_back(Context context, ArrayList<Damage_Item> Damage_Item) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Damage_Item = Damage_Item;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Damage_Item.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Damage_Item.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);
            button = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        }
        else
        {
        }

        button.setImageBitmap(Damage_Item.get(position).getTemp_image());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My `activity_manin.xml` file

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:padding="11dp"
        android:text="Add" />
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/describedamage_gridview"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

`row_grid.xml`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand what's the point to use a GridView inside a GridLayout... You might use only a GridView with 2 columns and add the ImageView dynamically. As I see, you're problem seems to recreate the adapter each time you pass in `onCaptureImageResult()`. You should create it once and refresh it by  calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

First it seems you not using holder pattern in your CustomAdapter_back also as Fllo noticed you don't need to remove manually the views. 
add this function to your adapter

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Damage_Item> data)
{
     this.Damage_Item = Damage_Item;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call this function from the dialog

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Whould you like to delete this image?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                     //get deleted item index according to your logic
                     int index = ((View) v.getParent()).getId() + 2;
                     gridArray.remove(index);
                     customGridAdapter.setData(gridArray);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

in on activityResult you have a 2 lines of code:

```
    customGridAdapter = new CustomAdapter_back(MainActivity.this, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
```

so every single time when you are adding a new image you are recreating the adapter.

Just move adapter declaration to onCreate with empty list. 
Add method

```
 public void addItem(Damage_Item item){
    this.Damage_Item.add(item); 
    this.notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

to your adapter and trigger it instead of creating adapter and setting new inside your onCaptureImageResult.

And for god sake, naming convention. Your code is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Damage_Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Damage_Item>();
CustomAdapter_back customGridAdapter;
GridLayout mContainerView;
int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
ImageView dynamic_imageview;
LinearLayout dynamic_linearview;
String image1;
ArrayList<String> arrayList_image = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContainerView = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.describedamage_gridview) ;
    //gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

    Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            inflateImageRow();
        }
    });
customGridAdapter = new CustomAdapter_back(MainActivity.this, gridArray);
    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

}

public void selectImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 140, 150, true);
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream1);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest); //bmp is the bitmap to dwaw into
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(resized, 0f, 0f, null);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(1, 145, 100, 130, paint);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float height = paint.measureText("yY");
    canvas.drawText(dateTime, 5f, height+130f, paint);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String image1 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    //arrayList_image.add(image1);
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(dest);
    //holder.imageItem.setBackground(background);
    Damage_Item damage_item = new Damage_Item();
    damage_item.setTemp_image(dest);
    gridArray.add(damage_item);

    customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    /*gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this)*/;



}
int count;
private void inflateImageRow() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_row, null);
    dynamic_imageview = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_imageview);

    dynamic_linearview=(LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynamic_linear);

        dynamic_imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //image_flagdynamic_right = true;
             selectImage();
        }
    });
    count= mContainerView.getChildCount()-1;
    dynamic_imageview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
        int parent=((View) v.getParent()).getId();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Whould you like to delete this image?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    int index = ((View) v.getParent()).getId() + 2;

                    try {
                        mContainerView.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                        // arrayList_image.remove(((View) v.getParent()).getId());
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

            return false;
        }
    });

    mContainerView.addView(rowView, mContainerView.getChildCount() - 1);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your xml by removing the GridView as the gridlayout should change the size of the image automatically.
Another non-recommended solution would be to use the screen dimensions for sizing your image